# date issue while converting a excel column to text

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

i have a excel file where one column will have data such as number , string , date etc. i want to convert that single column to text using VBA.

**Code:** (here i am trying to convert column A to text)

```
Sub Datatotext()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        xWs.Activate
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 2), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

**issue:**
after running the above code A column is converted to text but for Date values, month and date part are getting swapped and zero is removed.
example: 29/03/2033  ---converted to--> 3/29/2033. while the other data such as string ,number etc are stored as text without any issue. Please help me with this. i want the same data as text eg:29/03/2033 --> 29/03/2033

**input File:**
[input file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uho9Y1ZvF_2NXW-jclN4RYu2gHbkpWn_/view?usp=sharing)

[input file data after converting to text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ubzD7rlVXoklyUwJtoCGw0tu9gcfSQs-/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the exact value of the cell?

Comment: i have updated the question with the input files, please check it.

Comment: I cannot find the string value `29/03/2033` in the above file?

Comment: can you please check for value: 02-07-2068

Comment: no ti is not there. If you can see it then share the Cell Address

Comment: A17 cell has value  02-07-2068

Comment: no for me it shows as `7/2/2068`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221506/discussion-between-prabhaahar-and-siddharth-rout).

Comment: can you please download the file and open in excel. for me also it is showing as 7/2/2068 when i open it directly without downloading. moreover i guess that date format may differ on each system based on the system time zone and region setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, be really careful with your code, it will change the column A of every sheet in the workbook.

Try this code, it will convert every cell of the column in text and then the column type to text.

```
Dim rngColumn As Range
Dim cel As Variant
Dim usdRng As Long
Dim arr() As String
Dim count As Long
Dim xWs As Worksheet
' It's looping through the worksheets

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    'get last used row number
    usdRng = xWs.UsedRange.Rows.count
    Set rngColumn = xWs.Range("A1:A" & CStr(usdRng))
    
    ReDim arr(1 To usdRng)
    
    xWs.Range("A:A").Columns.AutoFit

    count = 1
    For Each cel In rngColumn
        arr(count) = cel.Text
        count = count + 1
    Next
    xWs.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
    xWs.Range("A1:A" & CStr(count-1)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention , my requirement was to change the column A of every sheet in the workbook.
  I tried with your above code , for some date values it is working fine , but for some date values it is getting converted to numbers . eg:02-07-2068 is getting changed to 61400.
input file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mfmpRytuU7nMCgw4ssT1JpIp7dhXlKW0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @prabhaahar I edited the code based on the input file. 
Try it and let me know if it's working.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo thanks for the help , above code is working fine as expected.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo , i have updated the input files . in the input file i have to convert the "G" column of every sheet to text so i just changed above code where A column is referenced to G. but when i ran the script in the sheet 2 some date value got changed to ######## . Please help me with this.

Comment: It's probably the collumn width, I edited the above code, change the columns to G again and it shall work

Comment: Hi @Rodrigo After runing the above code , date and other values are perfectly converted to text values but it is adding " #N/A " value to end of G column in all the sheets. eg: in G column last used cell is G37082 , then the script is adding #N/A to cell G37083 and similarly in other sheets too

Comment: it happens because the range is bigger then the array do xWs.Range("A1:A" & CStr(count - 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)

Comment: Hi @rodrigo.cantunes am facing a issue with vba code , please help me.
Input excel: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18SFG6H7FPYm0idODEDoR1BKKnuq2O7Xc/view?usp=sharing)
vba : [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VI7580MagYhVyyJTxqj4Qg0vFZxAyu2i/view?usp=sharing)
  After running the vba script to convert each sheets g column to text , on sheet "Attribute Group 0" on and below cell "B9417" the values are getting changed to "#N/A".